# how to access samba shares via nat?

Tags: 12.04, samba, nat

I have setup a virtual machine in Virtual Box and installed a Samba Server. I changed the guest operating system's NIC from Bridged to NAT for a reason that I can't remember. I then added a additional NIC in "host only adapter" mode. The Windows host OS now can access the Ubuntu 10.10 virtual server via the Host Only NIC. However, I can not access the Samba server running on the Ubuntu guest OS.

I am not sure what to do now. How can I get the widows Host OS to access the Guest OS' samba server.

Comment: You failed quality control because you didn't follow the basic rules of English. Sentences start with a CAPITOL letter.  Please remember this is a professional site and as such one should try to post as if they have at least a elementary understanding of English. Most people will help you out if English is not your first language. Heaven knows I can't spell well at all and sometimes my posts need editing, but you should at least try. Use a spell checker if needed. I have edited your question for you, this time.

Comment: Thank you for beautifying my text. What matters is to express the problem so that others may get it easily. Otherwise, what differ whether one use "a elementary" instead of "an elementary" or "samba" instead of "Samba"?! It's certainly not more "expressive".

Answer (score 0):

This will likely never work. Windows is likely not even looking at it's local virtual adapters for a file server. If you just want to share files between your host and guest setup Virtual Box Shared folders. [This link has good instructions](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868)

If you really want to share Samba between the two hosts your best option IMO, is to use "bridged" networking. This will put the virtual machine on the real network however.

Comment: Thank you (instead of thx!). You are right. I tried an additional host-only adapter as well as NAT. This causes the guest to has an ip address and resolves the problem. In another words, the samba is shared via host-only adapter instead of bridge. This causes host's internet to be shared for guest.